# Clarification on API plan subscription and production behaviour

Tags: docusignapi

I am using an integration key to provide customers the functionality to send documents and need clarification in purchasing a plan and production environment behavior. Can someone please help me by clarifying my below doubts

1) When an envelope is sent using an api, does it count in the envelope quota of the user's account 
    who has logged in or whose client id is used to make the api call(i.e my account)?

2) What does it mean by '1 user' mentioned in the pricing plan?

3) Will the customer logging in require any specific plan to use the apis(Eg: Basic api plan)? Will apis 
    work for customer with eSignature Plans or any production plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When an envelope is sent, the currently authenticated user's account is the one charged for the envelope. If you build an integration, but it runs off a customer's account, the customer's account is the one that's billed.

2) Multi-user accounts allow multiple different profiles for senders under the same account umbrella. This is appropriate for multiple senders in the same company, it's not appropriate for different companies or business units that must remain private/siloed, as admins will be able to access envelopes belonging to every user on the account.

3) All DocuSign accounts allow full API access to functionality that is available through the web console. So if one of your customers has a basic plan that does not allow the advanced recipient types, they will still be able to send envelopes using the functionality they have paid for.

If you're interested in developing an integration for use by other companies, I'd recommend looking into the DocuSign Partners Program: https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Drew. I would also like to know if **I can migrate my integration key to production using Basic API Plan**?

Comment: Yes, all of the API plans are valid for the Go Live process.